# Tensor product of a finitely generated abelian group and the field of rational numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, tensor-products

Let $G$ be a a finitely generated abelian group.
Then $G\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} = 0$ if and only if $G$ is a finite group.
The "if" part is easy. The "only if" part can be proved using [the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group).
Can we prove it without using the theorem?

Answer (score 6):

Let $F= \{f_1, \ldots, f_n\} \subseteq G$ a generating set. As $f_i \otimes 1 = 0$ for each $i$, there is a $m_i \in \mathbb Z$ such that $m_if_i = 0$. Hence 
$$ G \subseteq \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n k_i f_i \biggm| k_i\in \mathbb Z, \left|k_i\right| \le \left|m_i\right| 
 \right\} $$
and $G$ is finite.

---

Addendum: 
Consider the short exact sequence $0 \to K \to \mathbb Z \to G \to 0$ where $1 \mapsto f_i$ is the map from $\mathbb Z$ to $G$. Tensoring with $\mathbb Q$ gives us the short exact $K \otimes \def\Q{\mathbb Q}\Q \to \mathbb Q \to 0 \to 0$. Hence $K \otimes \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ is onto, but $K$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$, so $K \ne 0$, say $K = n \mathbb Z$ with $n \ne 0$, giving $nf_i = 0$.

Comment: Could you explain why there exists such $m_i$?

Comment: @MakotoKato Added something

Comment: I'm afraid that the sequence $0 \to K \to \mathbb Z \to G \to 0$ is not exact in general. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be an abelian group, then $A\otimes \mathbb{Z}_m\cong A/mA$ as abelian groups. If $A$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, then clearly $\mathbb{Q}/m\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial.

As you request, the other direction is proved without using the fundamental theorem. Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group, then at least one of the generator has infinite order. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow G$, and $\mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}\otimes G\ne0$.